# Cocos2d set display frame Async

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocos2d-iphone

So I am making a kids game which is like the following :

I have around 118 different **CENTER_OBJECTS** like Apple , Ball , Cat etc which will be placed in the center and **ALPHABETS** revolve around it , so when you click on the correct alphabet you move and the **CENTER_OBJECT** is replaced .

The problem that I am facing is that when the display frame of the CENTER_OBJECT is replaced , 
I observe a slight lag in the alphabets that are moving around . I am pretty sure that it is **caused by setting the display frame to that of new word[image: Center Object is some word like APPLE , BOY and blue boxes are ALPHABETS]** .

I am **caching** the Sprite sheet for each **CENTER_OBJECT asynchronously** . So is there some way that you can suggest to stop this slight lag ?

**EDIT**

Well , before the player starts playing , I would cache 5 center objects ,and when only 2 of the cache objects are remaining , I start caching the next 5 items . So what I have is a function for that :

```
-(void)getNext5RandomsForHalf:(NSInteger)half{
int i;

// half is just a way to preload , alternatively 1st half
// or 2nd half is used for cached Center Objects 
if (half==0) {

    i=0;
}else
{
    i=5;
}

for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {

  NSInteger objectIndex;

  do {
        objectIndex=(arc4random()%[self.centerObjects count]);
  } while (playedObjects[objectIndex]==1);

  playedObjects[objectIndex]=1;

  batchRandomObjects[j+i]=objectIndex; // this is used to store precalculated 
                                       //random numbers 

  NSString *tempString = (NSString*)[self.centerObjects objectAtIndex:j];
  NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",tempString];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:filename];
CCLOG(@"%@ file added",filename);
    }


    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


         // Code for Starting the play for the first time . 
         if (justStarted) {

            [self playForNextObjectWithNumberOfLetters:self.numberOfLetters];
            justStarted=NO;
        }
    });
});

}
```

In my playForNextObjectWithNumberOfLetters: I declare and initialise the game object : CenterObject , and set its display frame accordingly . So I have property called NSString* centerObjectName which is overridden by me for display frame purpose

```
-(void)setCenterObjectName:(NSString*)name
{

_centerObjectName = [name retain];


        CCSpriteFrame* frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache
sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:_centerObjectName];

self.displayFrame = frame;

}
```

Comment: post the relevant code. Note that asynch loading may make no difference if you load only at the moment you need to display the texture

Comment: No , I am loading it before time . And even if I am loading at the moment , I think that it shouldn't create a lag if I am loading that too in the background and once that ends if I set the display frame.

Comment: How large are the files? Cocos2D will clear unused sprites from the cache when memory is low.

Comment: The images are around 620 x 520 in size .

Comment: Is this on the simulator or device? What kind of lag on the animation and for how long?